# How to use AJAX & JSON with an API to call multiple URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have several areas in which I need to take information and append it to my main HTML document, from separate pages that are generated with a weather API.

For instance, in the Current Conditions section, I need to reference "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6905d444cd421efb/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/CT/New_Haven.json" but in my Hourly Forecast, I would need to be drawing the JSON info from "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6905d444cd421efb/hourly/q/CT/New_Haven.json" and then I need to repeat that same process again in a third separate section with another url for a 10 day forecast. Each time I call to a new URL, I will be creating new variables and appending their results to the DOM.

The code that I have below works, but if I try calling to the ajax method a second or third time, it does not work and things either show up as "undefined" or absolutely nothing shows on the page in the other sections. The only thing that remains displayed on my web page is the Current Conditions.

```js
$.ajax({                             
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6905d444cd421efb/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/CT/New_Haven.json",
  dataType : "json", 
  success : function(parsed_json) {
    
   var current_icon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon_url'];
   var current_weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
   var location = parsed_json['location']['city']; 
   var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
   var current_feels = parsed_json ['current_observation']['feelslike_f'];
   var current_humidity = parsed_json ['current_observation']['relative_humidity'];
   var current_windDirection = parsed_json ['current_observation']['wind_dir'];
   var current_windMPH = parsed_json ['current_observation']['wind_mph'];
  
  $("#icon").append("<img src=' " + current_icon + "' alt='weather icon'/>" );
     
  $("#currentCond").append("Current Conditions: " + current_weather);
  
  $("#currentLoc").append("Location: " + location);
  
  $("#currentTemp").append(" Temp: " + temp_f + "ºF");
  
  $("#currentFeel").append("Feels Like: " + current_feels + "ºF");
  
  $("#currentHumid").append("Humidity: " + current_humidity);
  
  $("#currentWindDir").append("Wind Direction: " + current_windDirection);

  $("#currentWindMph").append("Wind Speed: " + current_windMPH + " MPH"); 

  }/* Close Success */  
 }); /* Close Ajax  */
```

I try adding something like this after the first call is closed out.

```js
$.ajax({                             
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6905d444cd421efb/hourly/q/CT/New_Haven.json",
  dataType : "json", 
  success : function(parsed_json2) {
    
   var hourly_icon = parsed_json2['hourly_forecast']['icon_url'];
   var hourly_icons = parsed_json2['hourly_forecast']['icon'];
   
   $("#icons").append("Icon Type: " + hourly_icons);
  
   $("#icons").append("<img src=' " + hourly_icon + "' alt='weather icon'/>" );
    

  }/* Close Success */  
 }); /* Close Ajax  */
```

Comment: Just curious... does this http://api.wunderground.com limit how many ajax calls you can make? Could be why the calls only work the first time

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it doesn't limit it, but how would I be able to find out for sure?

Comment: Look [here](http://api.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html) then goto the "How much will you use our service?" it looks like you are limited to 10 calls per minute if you aren't paying anything. This doesn't mean that this is your problem though... just something to look out for

Comment: Alright. I don't really know if that's what my problem is, but it might be. I've been testing this site a lot, especially when messing around with errors and whatnot. I don't think that it's my problem, because if it was, it wouldn't be displaying the first section properly. Everything would be broken.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(parsed_json);` in your `success` function. Usually if you are being throttled you'll get a message like "limit reached" in the json return instead of your data.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8hur14 - This is what it looks like.

Comment: Did what you suggested and it's not throttling it, everything works until I try and call to the ajax method a second time. It's telling me "file not found" when it gets to the second call.